# Magento2 change price to not required

Tags: magento2

I am currently setting up a store but 
I don't have all the product prices yet, however the price fields is required I wanted to know if it is possible to change this

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Admin Panel

1. menu Stores, select Product
2. search in attribute listing page with 'price'
3. than edit to **Values Required -> Yes** to **Values Required to No**

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin > Store > Attributes > Product` and find price attribute and set `value required = No` check below image for your referance.
[image]

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's working. It'll help other people to find a batter solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this thread and I have done both of these steps but it still is showing price as a required field. I have tried logging out and back in again after saving the changes and it still hasn't worked. Any ideas?